# how to install sabrent usb to serial adapter drivers?

Tags: drivers

I am really new to linux Ubuntu 12.04  and just starting to figure things out, could someone give me a install guide for the Sabrent SBT_USC6K usb to serial adapter. I have the install cd here with the drivers if needed

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from their driver package they provide drivers for Redhat Linux only.

If you look into the Linux Folder and extract the file `SBT-USCxxLinux.rar` you get 3 folders named `Redhat73`, `Redhat8` and `Redhat9`.

I looked some more and found several references to "Prolific", adapters with those chipsets are *supposed* to work without any additional drivers, please see if answers to the old question [How to connect to a terminal to Serial-USB device on ubuntu 10.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347962/how-to-connect-to-a-terminal-to-serial-usb-device-on-ubuntu-10-10) on Stackoverflow can help you.